# VST alternative for TSE x30 Default Settings

Tags: audio-recording, vst, distortion, guitar

I've currently found a nice set of Guitar impulses that I'd like to starting getting in to, unfortunately they all require the [TSE x30](http://www.tseaudio.com/software/tseX30) on default settings. As I'm on a Mac, I can't get this specific VST loaded.

How can I replicate this sound on my setup?  Would anyone have an alternative for that sound but on a Mac? Podfarm, Guitar Rig, Amplitube, or even something else, I'm willing to work with anything if it means matching the sound.

Comment: hi, unless this setup is used for sound design, i think this is off topic. can you elaborate on the sound design aspect or detail on what you are trying to create, because it seems off topic to ask for technical alternatives.

Comment: @ArnoudTraa - I'm not sure I see how this is any different from a request for finding a sound.  He knows what plug in gives the sound he wants, but it isn't compatible with his system, so he is looking for an alternate way to produce the same sound.  That seems pretty sound design related to me.

Comment: What may be critical here is whether or not the default settings for the tse x30 has any 'sound' of its own. If it does not really colour the sound, then it may be substituted effectively.
If it has a character sound of its own in the default position, then you may wish to capture that sound as a primary impulse and move on from there.